# how to convert sub-domain URL to domain URL using smarty

Tags: regex, smarty

I have a URL like this

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/xyz-200_some_information
```

I want to convert this URL to following URL using smarty.

```
http://www.domain.com/xyz-200_some_information
```

That is, need to replace `subdomain` with `www`

`subdomain` is not fixed, there may be more more subdomains. I'm looking for a smarty based solution instead of a PHP one, as I don't have to acc change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `regex_replace`

```
{$var|regex_replace:"/http:\/\/.*?\./":"http://www."}
```

This matches a region from `http://` to the first dot and replaces it with `http://www.`

Comment: Here we don't know the names of "subdomain"

Comment: Revised to exclude subdomain specificity.